# Create dynamic class instances in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

I am working with webpack, typescript 2.8, es5.

I want to create dynamic class instances from variable names for example:

```
protected handleAfterInit(page) : void 
{

    let instance: any;
    let pageName: string = this.capitalizeFirstLetter(page);

    console.log(pageName);

    instance = Object.create((window[pageName]).prototype);
    instance.constructor.apply(instance);

    console.log(instance);
}
```

Where pageName is a variable (Home, About etc) and those classes are already imported on top of the page:

```
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { About } from "./About";
```

But with current code I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

It seems that there is no window.{class}

Is it possible to do something like this in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you import the classes `Home` and `About` from a module they are not in the `window` object.

The simplest way to do this, would be to use a constructor signature:

```
protected handleAfterInit(page: new () => any): void {
    let instance = new page()
}
```

If you need access pages by name you can create a map with pages and then call the avbove method:

```
pagesByName : { [name: string] :new () => any } = {Home, About};
protected handleAfterInitByName(pageName: string): void {
    this.handleAfterInit(this.pagesByName [pageName]);
}
```

Also you can replace the `any` in `new () => any` with a base class for all pages to give yo better type checking.

Answer (score 0):

`window[pageName]` gets the global variable named `pageName`.

Variables or imports in modules do not create global variables, so that won't work.

Instead, you should create your own map:

```
const pages = {Home, About};
pages[pageName]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing the classes, you should put them in your own object, and then use it to construct new instances:

```
const constructors = {Home, About, ...};
const instance = constructors[pageName](); // pageName should be 'Home', 'About' ...
```